# xslt 2.0 filter out elements who have certain attributes that are listed in a different file

Tags: xslt

I have elements with a certain number of child elements. The child elements look something like this:

```
<checker val="this" some="yuppi" here="there" what="nothing"/>
```

Some of these attributes act as a filter. I don't know which ones and how many in advance. I have to look that up in a different file that contains all the attributes used as a filter at that particular time. That file basically looks like this:

```
<someElem >
<f name="val" value="this"/>
<f name="other" value="that"/>
<f name="val" value="something"/>
</someElem>
<someElem >
<f name="val" value="this"/>
<f name="other" value="that"/>
<f name="some" value="yuppi"/>
</someElem>
```

So on a different occasion, with different source material, there may be more or less or different filter attributes.

I know which element in the look-up file to choose, because it has the same id as an element which is the parent element of the checker-elements. Basically, the parent elements of the checker-elements have a filter applied that filters out certain checker-elements.

What I ultimately want to achieve is this: I have an element which has lots of checker-elements as child elements and I only want to copy those checker elements into a new file that dont have any attributes listed in the look-up file, the filter file.

So in the example above, the checker element would not get copied into the new file because it has a `val` attribute and the corresponding element in the look-up file is the first one and it has an f-element whose name is `val`. That's enough for me to know that it should be disregared. The same would happen if the checker element had an attribute called `other`.

My current approach is something like this:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('test', @id, $elemFile)">
            <xsl:if test="@id = $curID">
            <xsl:variable name="curElemID" select="@id"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="node()"> <!-- these here are the checker-elements from the example. They are child nodes of another element that I am iterating over -->
                <xsl:variable name="curElem" select="."/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*"> <!-- looking at each of the attributes of the checker-element -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$lookupfile//someElem[@id = $curElemID]//f/@name = local-name()"> <!-- check if the current checker-element has one of the attributes whose local-name is the same as the name-attribute value of the corresponding someElem element -->
                            <xsl:message>
                            <xsl:text>Hit </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$curElem/@id"/>
                            </xsl:message>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$curElem"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>   
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Right now, the elements get copied into the new file even if they have one of the attributes.

Whats the best way to code this?

I hope I was able to explain my problem...

Thanks in advance for tips and help!

**EDIT**

A hopefully clearer example.

The file with the checker elements:

```
<root>
<abc id="someId">
<checker val="this" test="testest" here="there" what="nothing"/>
<checker some="yuppi" here="there" />
<checker other="that"/>
</abc>
<abc id="someOtherId">
<checker val="this" some="yuppi" here="there" what="nothing"/>
<checker some="yuppi" here="there" what="nothing"/>
<checker attr="val""/>
</abc>
</root>
```

the look-up file:

```
<someElem id="someId"> <!-- filter that gets applied to the first abc element-->
<f name="val" value="this"/>
<f name="other" value="that"/>
<f name="val" value="something"/>
</someElem>
<someElem id="someOtherId"> <!-- filter that gets applied to the second abc element-->
<f name="other" value="that"/>
<f name="some" value="yuppi"/>
</someElem>
```

Expected output:

```
<new>
<abc id="someId">
<checker some="yuppi" here="there" />
</abc>
<abc id="someOtherId">
<checker attr="val""/>
</abc>
</new>
```

in the first abc element, the first checker element gets filtered out because in the someElem that has the same id as the abc element, the filters specified are val and other - the first checker element has an attribute called val.

The third checker element gets filtered out because it has an attribute called other

in the second abc element, the first two checker elements get filtered out because of the same rule. They have at least one attribute that is specified as a filter.

Comment: This is very confusing. Please provide a small, but complete(!) example of the two files, and the expected output of the transformation. -- Hint: use a **key** to perform a lookup.

Comment: I hope my edit helps!

Comment: Do you look for a match based only on the name of the attribute? Or do you require a match of both name and value?

Comment: The name of the attribute is sufficient, because the filter says "if it is has one of the attributes, I gets filtered out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use something like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookupdoc" select="'path/to/your/other/file.xml'" />
<xsl:key name="f" match="f" use="../@id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <new>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc">
    <xsl:variable name="x-names" select="key('f', @id, document($lookupdoc))/@name" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="checker[not(@*[name()=$x-names])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: both your files must be well-formed for this to work; currently neither of them is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Ill try working that into my code.